# Invisible Plane that catches light from emissive surfaces

Tags: rendering, light, visibility

i am trying to make a lighsaber in blender 2.81 to add to some footage. i am trying to make a light emission from the lightsaber onto a plane directly behind it, but i dont know how to make the plane invisible so i can still use a transparent render background. any help would be greatly appreciaated. [image]thanks in advance.

Comment: I recently discovered that if you switch into Eevee that the bloom function will actually do this for me